# Multi-page Safecracker forms

Tags: safecracker, forms

I'm working on a project where new members will create a channel entry using Safecracker. I have something in place but have decided I'd like to break the form up into multiple pages to better walk them through things.

I've seen this post at Ellislab forums, http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/166104/, and it looks to be workable.

What I'd like to do is create pages with 4-5 fields each, and have the form saved when moving to the next page, where they'd just edit the next set of fields, through to the last page where the form is saved again.

In theory, this means that I can link back to a page if they need to redo something and they would just be re-editing those fields.

Am I off-base on this? I haven't set up Safecracker this way before.

Comment: Kelly - what did you end up doing with this? I need a multipage form set up that sends an email when the final page is completed. Thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

According to the docs the `ENTRY_ID` constant still exists and is what Rob is referring to in [his reply](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/166104/#795010):

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/index.html#return

Not positive though, one thing you may need to watch out for is required custom fields on the EE (and Safecraker) side of things. You could implement something on the frontend ala html5 and one of the jQuery form plugins instead.

With that said, my answer would be to just try it :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you might want to try something like what I set up on [**this form**](http://www.destinationcolorado.com/submit-rfp).

It's a multi-step form process without having to split the form over multiple pages. Sections are shown or hidden with jQuery.